# What Leo is referring to by say "know" in his reply?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Leo: But my childhood, for example, I do not remember a thing about
>   it. There is only one thing I still remember.
>
> Alan: What?
>
> Leo: The precise moment when I learned how to ride a bike. And this
>   morning. As if by magic I remembered the moment right after...
>
> Alan: When you fell off?
>
> Leo: How the f*ck did you **know**?
>
> Alan: Well, that happens to everybody. You learn something, you're
>   happy and then. you forget to brake.

I didn't understand What Leo is referring to by say "know" in his reply?, Alan is asking a question: When you fell off?, But Leo replied differently.

Comment: How did you know [I fell off]. This is very common in daily speech when you don't have to tell everything because it can be retrieved from the context. I believe it's also common in your native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that "When you fell off?" is not in the usual question form: "When did you fall off?" That is because it is not a full sentence, but just a phrase, spoken with question intonation. Alan is not asking a "when" question.

In English, it is possible to ask a yes/no question with intonation. You can ask "Do you want a cigarette?" by saying "Cigarette?". By intonation and context, the question is understood (It's funny if [someone doesn't understand](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=het1kl-A8qw)) If Alan asked a complete question he would say "Is the time that you remembered the time *when you fell off* your bike?".

Leo understands the question. But instead of answering it, he responds with his own question "How did you know [that I remembered falling off my bike]?" Nothing unusual about this. His response implies that Alan had guessed right. English like (probably) all natural languages, allows for ellipsis when the context is clear. The response to a question can be another question.